# How to enable csrf support for swagger-ui and swagger-codegen

Tags: angular, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I have an application which is built using Spring Boot and Angular 6. I have also  generated API clients using `Swagger-codegen`. Everything was working fine but recently it was found that application was vulnerable to CSRF. So, I have implemented the CSRF token within cookie by using `CsrfTokenRepository` on server side, like this:

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(CSRF_IGNORE).csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

and for Angular :

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN'}),
```

Now, the application is working fine, but the swagger-ui and generared API clients are not working. It throws:

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.

I have searched for this and found some issues for `swagger` and `springfox-swagger-ui`. Particularly, this was very useful https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1450. But I didn't found any idea about how can I use this or is this possible or not. On most of the other places, developers are ignoring `swagger-ui` from CSRF.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks